# How to get data usages of application in lower versions of android?

Tags: android, android-version, android-data-usage

I'm building an application which shows the **data-usage** and **usage-time** of applications by using telephonic service. But I'm unable to get this data in **pre-marshmallow** devices. I have tried the different solutions from other answers on stackowerflow but nothing worked for me. Please anyone help to get any of data-usage or usage-time(i.e. how much time the app was used per day).